# Localhost not loading in any browser

Tags: html, sql-server, iis, asp-classic, installation

I have asked a similar question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632597/iis-localhost-not-loading/25647432#25647432) I sort of fixed it but im still facing a similar issue. Every time I try to load localhost, port 8095, I receive this error message in Google Chrome:

> Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The
>   website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.

If there is a way to fix it, please tell me,

If not, please could someone inform me how to reset IIS to its original settings. Or if I can reset Windows Features so I can re-install ISS from scratch.

My website uses ASP with a connection to a SQL Server database (2012). Basic HTML pages also don't load under the URL, localhost:8095/

Comment: Are you sure your app is running in IIS under that port?

Comment: reset iis from cmd by typing iisreset.Before that make sure your firewall is not blocking the connections.

Comment: maybe this can be useful [localhost not working](http://superuser.com/questions/713491/why-does-localhost-not-work-in-windows-8-1-but-127-0-0-1-does)

Comment: @MairajAhmad thank you, just what I needed, I'll do this when I can, It's on my laptop at home. I'll update you with any ore questions if that's okay :)

Comment: @DavidG yes, the ports are fine, when I press browse in IIS, I still get the same error

Comment: please inform if any issue.

Comment: Hove you tried port 80 - which IIS usually uses?

Comment: @John no but I tried 8080 and it told me to change it. Should I try it?

Comment: Obviously I don't know everything about your setup, but if you don't have another webserver (eg Apache) running already on port 80 then I don't see why it shouldn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The servers were stopped because 2 services within administrative tools had stopped. World Wide Web Publishing Service and Web Management Service