# Debugging ASP.NET webapp in chrome

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, google-chrome, autodesk-forge

I'm following a [tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-aspnet-zero-hero-30-minutes) from autodesk forge to create an ASP.NET webapp with Visual Studio. When I attempt to debug my code in chrome, I get the errors:

Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.

[image: Attaching the WebKit debugger failed]

Comment: Visual Studio is trying to link to the running website through Chrome.  Do you have BrowserLink enabled? If so, turn it off.  http://dailydotnettips.com/2013/08/30/refreshing-browsers-directly-from-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: With BrowserLink disabled the errors did not change; however, the following error was shown additionally. http://imgur.com/67e8jSF

Comment: Is this the first website you've attempted to run since you installed Visual Studio?  What happens when you try changing to other browsers near the "start" icon?  Have you closed and opened Visual Studio?

Comment: This is the first website I've attempted to run. I have tried Microsoft Edge and Vivaldi with similar results. I have open, closed, and recreated the project in a different repository with no change in results.

Comment: Hi @KevinEdwards, Please bear with me checking with you on whether it can work well if you test with a blank ASP.NET project. the error you hit looks not related with Forge and there are couple possibilities such error might happen. I tried to search and found one which probably helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684087/localhost-not-loading-in-any-browser

Comment: When tested with a blank project, I get the following output:

The program '[22468] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
https://imgur.com/a/HMfcC
I have tried iisreset and renaming my iisexpress folder to no avail.

Comment: I would say that your VS & IIS are corrupted, or at least need repair, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27155236/4838205